# How can I read from two different CSV files and create two different arrays without duplicating code?

Tags: java

This is my code. Im reading data from two CSV files (one for users and one for restaurants) and Im supplying two different test classes in Selenium Webdriver with two different arrays in order to parametrize the tests.

Is there any way I dont repeat so much code here?

```
final String FILE_PATH = "src/test/resources/250.csv";
final String FILE_PATH2 = "src/test/resources/places.csv";

    //read CSV file and supply data for test purposes
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(FILE_PATH));
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    String[] nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // 5 is the number of columns
            list.add(nextLine[i]);
        }
        array.add(list);

    }
    reader.close();

    CSVReader reader2 = new CSVReader(new FileReader(FILE_PATH2));
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    String[] nextLine2;
    while ((nextLine2 = reader2.readNext()) != null) {
        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // 5 is the number of columns
            list2.add(nextLine2[i]);
        }
        array2.add(list2);

    }
    reader2.close();
```

Comment: I am wondering, what's this application you're working on, I saw three or four questions asked by you and related with this application.

Comment: This is a set of Selenium Webdriver tests that emulate user behavior in a Firefox browser. Tests are parametrized, they capture a screenshot and send email upon failure. They are automatically started in a Continuous Integration development environment on new code deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getCSVContent(String filepath) throws Exception {
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(FILE_PATH));
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    String[] nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // 5 is the number of columns
            list.add(nextLine[i]);
        }
        array.add(list);
    }
    reader.close();
    return array;
}
```

Comment: ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array1 = getCSVContent(FILE_PATH);

Answer (score 3):

How about declaring a ... **function**

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fromFileToArray(String filename)
```

Comment: ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fromFileToArray(String filename)

Answer (score 1):

```
  List<List<String>> getList(String filePath){
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    String[] nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // 5 is the number of columns
            list.add(nextLine2[i]);
        }
        array.add(list);

    }
    reader.close();

    return array;
  }
```

- getList(FILE_PATH)
- getList(FILE_PATH2)

Answer (score 1):

You create a method as below

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> read (FileReader reader)
{
   CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(reader);
   ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
   String[] nextLine;
   while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // 5 is the number of columns
        list.add(nextLine[i]);
    }
    array.add(list);

}
reader.close();
return array;
}
```

Then you can call the method as below twice

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array1 = read(new FileReader(FILE_PATH));
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array2 = read(new FileReader(FILE_PATH2));
```